# не работает mobilenet

Tags: javascript, html, tensorflow

tensorflow установлен, но как только пытаюсь сделать предикт выводит

````
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Tensorflow Op is not supported: _FusedConv2D
    mapNode http://127.0.0.1:5500/risovalka/tensorflow.js:2
    a http://127.0.0.1:5500/risovalka/tensorflow.js:2
    transformGraph http://127.0.0.1:5500/risovalka/tensorflow.js:2
    Oy http://127.0.0.1:5500/risovalka/tensorflow.js:2
    s http://127.0.0.1:5500/risovalka/tensorflow.js:2
    s http://127.0.0.1:5500/risovalka/tensorflow.js:2
    a http://127.0.0.1:5500/risovalka/tensorflow.js:2
    promise callback*u http://127.0.0.1:5500/risovalka/tensorflow.js:2
    Bg http://127.0.0.1:5500/risovalka/tensorflow.js:2
    Bg http://127.0.0.1:5500/risovalka/tensorflow.js:2
    load http://127.0.0.1:5500/risovalka/tensorflow.js:2
    loadGraphModel http://127.0.0.1:5500/risovalka/tensorflow.js:2
    s http://127.0.0.1:5500/risovalka/tensorflow.js:2
    s http://127.0.0.1:5500/risovalka/tensorflow.js:2
    Bg http://127.0.0.1:5500/risovalka/tensorflow.js:2
    Bg http://127.0.0.1:5500/risovalka/tensorflow.js:2
    loadGraphModel http://127.0.0.1:5500/risovalka/tensorflow.js:2
    s http://127.0.0.1:5500/risovalka/mobilenet.js:2
    s http://127.0.0.1:5500/risovalka/mobilenet.js:2
    s http://127.0.0.1:5500/risovalka/mobilenet.js:2
    r http://127.0.0.1:5500/risovalka/mobilenet.js:2
    r http://127.0.0.1:5500/risovalka/mobilenet.js:2
    load http://127.0.0.1:5500/risovalka/mobilenet.js:2
    load http://127.0.0.1:5500/risovalka/mobilenet.js:2
    s http://127.0.0.1:5500/risovalka/mobilenet.js:2
    s http://127.0.0.1:5500/risovalka/mobilenet.js:2
    r http://127.0.0.1:5500/risovalka/mobilenet.js:2
    r http://127.0.0.1:5500/risovalka/mobilenet.js:2
    load http://127.0.0.1:5500/risovalka/mobilenet.js:2
    predict http://127.0.0.1:5500/risovalka/risovalka.js:6
    onclick http://127.0.0.1:5500/risovalka/risovalka.html:1
    ```


на всякий прикладываю весь проект 
<https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sucnVDYgTjj99tU3VvO0hkSUrvBeKewD/view?usp=sharing>
````